# how do i turn on group chat for my nokia 635

Tags: messaging

My Nokia recently got restarted, and now when I try to send a group message it wont go through and says that I have to change my settings. I can't find where these text message/ group message settings are. Any help on how to turn group chat back on?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it on by going to the Messaging app, tapping on the three dots in the bottom right corner, then going to Settings > turn on group messaging. There's also more information on messaging [here](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/calling-and-messaging/send-a-text).